# Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test in Python Scipy on brain data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I have brain anatomy measurements from 2 different groups of individuals. One group has more individuals than the other (say n and m individuals each). I have to run the KS test on this data. I am a little unclear about the arguments to pass to the scipy two sample KS test. Will arguments to the scipy 2 sample ks test be every individual from group 1 against every individual in group 2 in a for loop ? Or is it every feature in group 1 against every other feature in group 2 ?

I wrote this code but it's obviously wrong as i am using iteritems() to loop over the columns when perhaps it should be n*m ?

```
for group1, group2 in zip(group1.transpose().iteritems(), 
group2.transpose().iteritems()):

    value, pvalue = ks_2samp(np.array(group1[1]), np.array(group2[1]))
    print(value, pvalue)
    if pvalue > 0.05:
        print('Samples are likely drawn from the same distributions 
        (fail to reject H0)')
    else: 
        print('Samples are likely drawn from the different 
        distributions (reject H0)')
```

Comment: add some data to reproduce your error

Comment: I think you need the empirical distribution functions of each group and then compare those.

Comment: Because you have used both the `tranpose()` and `iteritems()` methods, I assume that `group1` and `group2` are Pandas `DataFrame`s.  Is that correct?

Comment: Also, what are `asd` and `control`?   You haven't defined them in your code.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes, they are pandas dataframes.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser sorry, asd and control are group1 and group2 respectively. Edited code.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say one of the measurements is brain mass.  Gather all the brain mass measurements for group 1 into a sequence (or 1-d array), and do the same for group 2.  Pass these two sequences to `ks_2samp`.  That will test whether the brain masses of the two groups come from the same distribution.

For example, if `group1` and `group2` are Pandas DataFrames with a row for each individual and with columns for the different measurements associated with each individual, including one called "mass" for brain mass, you would do:

```
value, pvalue = ks_2samp(group1['mass'].to_numpy(), group2['mass'].to_numpy())
```

Comment: thanks very much.but as for the reason/intuition behind doing so, what we're doing here is checking if two different individuals, supposedly one having some unique mental condition and the other typical, are from the same group.is that correct?so, during feature selection,i'd be well advised not to select those features that seem to come from the same distribution acc. to the KS 2 sample test. is that correct?

Comment: Are you asking a *programming question* (i.e. how to use `ks_2samp`), or a *statistics* question (e.g. what is the KS test, and can I use it for my data)?  If the latter, your question is better asked over at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).